# Keycloak Client adapter for Play Framework

Tags: playframework, single-sign-on, netty, saml-2.0, keycloak

Is there a keycloak client adapter for **Netty** servers. In main keycloak documentation, they have mentioned several client adapters (http://www.keycloak.org/downloads.html) but I didn't see any specification on Netty. My requirement is to enable **SAML** based **SSO** for **Service Providers** build in **Play Framework** using **Keycloak** as the **IdP**. Since Play framework uses Netty as the underlying server, I want to know whether there is a Keycloak client adapter for Play framework or Netty?

Comment: Curious if you ever got an answer to this. Would like to integrate our Play 1.x app to Keycloak for SSO

Comment: Couldn't find a Netty client adapter, but this should be possible via **pact4j** (https://github.com/pac4j/pac4j). It has support for **Open-Id** connect, hence should be possible to integrate with **Keycloak**.